# Perform Segue Programmatically Without Button Connection?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uistoryboard, segue

I have two view controllers in my storyboard and I need to push from view 1 to view 2.

I need to do this without connecting a segue directly from a button in my storyboard, I need to do it programatically.

How can I?

Thanks.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

When you click the button call:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueIdentifier" sender:self];
```

You will need to create the segue in the storyboard but you can do it from view controller to view controller instead of button to viewcontroller.

Comment: This make the navigation so weird. It doesn't animate, also the destination view take too long time to layout. Any idea?

Comment: What is the difference between this and using the navigation stack?

Comment: @Subby you have to use Navigation controller for moving to next view either Segue or Navigation stack. But using Segue controller puts a visual wiring in your storyboard and you can visually see each screen source and destination. This is very helpful when you have 30 to 40 screens in your app

Comment: Thanks Stu! Almost 10 yrs later, still working in Xcode 14.  Modifying my app to add a horizontal scroll view with buttons to navigate to about 10 other view (getting rid of Next/Back buttons to move 1 screen at a time like a book). This is awesome. Users will be very happy.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform an action without click (or while loading the viewController itself), do this code in either

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NameOfYourSequeIdentifier" sender:self];
 }
```

or

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NameOfYourSequeIdentifier" sender:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Completely w/o segues

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourViewControllerIDinStoryBoard"] animated:YES];
```