# Cannot click back button when open view from remote notirication

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-push-notifications

My iOS application using Objective C. It received a remote notification, when a user click it, it will open a particular view.

This view has a back button in the navigation tab. In normal scenarios can back to root view. However, when I open this view from a notification, cannot back to any view nor leaving the application.

Here is my spruce code:
 1. from AppDelegate.m to open a particular view:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

UIViewController *viewAnnouncement =[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Announcement"];

self.window.rootViewController = viewAnnouncement;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

2. Action function to back to previous view (in viewClass.m):

   ```
   - (IBAction)onBtnBackClicked:(id)sender {
       [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
   ```

I believe the problem is, when I open this view from a notification, no parent view to let it back to. Can anyone help me, when user open this view from a notification, whether it goes to a root view or back to the previous opening app

Comment: are you set the `viewAnnouncement` as `rootViewController` then how will you get the previous VC

Comment: Coz when I open the app from notification, I want this view to show immediately. Is there another way to set this viewAnnouncement ?

Comment: use present option

Comment: I found a way to solve it, thanks and all the besy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. My app has multiple views which I can go from a navigation list. When I want to back to main view, I just dismiss the current view.

Cuurently, a view is opened when I click a notification and I can't simply dismiss this view, Coz it considered as root view.

What I did to solve it, I connect my view (Announcement) by segue to main view, and set an identifier (for example: "leaveAnnouncementPage". Then, in your class just call this function in back button's fnction to back to the main view:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"leaveAnnouncementPage" sender:self];
```

Here is also some useful links:

[First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654003/perform-segue-programmatically-without-button-connection)

[Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674685/creating-a-segue-programmatically)

Thank you guys for your help, and all the best

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : The previous answer didn't take in count the fact that you were in `AppDelegate`. Maybe this answer is better.

---

Turn your `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]`

into :

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
UIViewController *yourPreviousVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    [navigationController pushViewController:yourPreviousVC animated:YES];
```

If I'm wrong or if I missunderstood the question, do not hesitate to correct my answer.

Comment: how will you get the `self` in `AppDelegate`

Comment: My bad ! I apology I didn't see it was in `AppDelegate` ! Thanks for your comment.

Comment: its ok my bro, can you modify the answer

Comment: Thanks for your help, I found the solution and I'll post it here.

Comment: Great ! Thanks for sharing your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Announcement *annouce = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Announcement"];
HomeVC *home = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeVC"];
[((UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController) setViewControllers:@[home,annouce] animated:YES];
```

And If app already open and you want to go previous page

```
Announcement *annouce = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Announcement"];
UIViewController *visibleView = ((UINavigationController *)window.rootViewController).visibleViewController;
[((UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController) setViewControllers:@[visibleView,annouce] animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I appreciate that